# Django: How do I get a nested foreignkey to continuously display?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

For academic purposes, I am creating software that can manage a company's clients, project, and staff members. I figured out that by referencing a foreignkey in a separate model, you can get two models to display next to each other and be related. The problem is, is that it only displays one item for each model.

For example: You have a project your company is working on. In the admin section, it displays the project name and a single staff member. However, it should be displaying 2+ staff members.

Here's the file layout (I tried creating a separate app for different fields clients being the primary and projects the secondary):

clients.admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from clients.models import Status, Project, Staff_Member, Client

class StatusInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Status
    extra = 0



class Staff_MemberInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Staff_Member
    extra = 5
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class ProjectInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Project

    extra = 1

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,  {'fields': ['name']}),


    ]
    inlines = [ProjectInline, StatusInline]

    search_fields = ['name']



admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
#admin.site.register(Project)
admin.site.register(Staff_Member)
```

## next file

clients.models:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    #def was_published_recently(self):
    #   return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    #was_published_recently.admin_order_filed = 'pub_date'
    #was_published_recently.boolean = True
    #was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'

class Status(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    #staff_member = models.ForeignKey(Staff_Member)
    #project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    status_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def stat(self):
        return self.status_text
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status_text









class Staff_Member(models.Model):
    #status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    #project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    #client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    staff_member_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.staff_member_text

    def mem(self):
        return self.staff_member_text

class Project(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    project_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    staff_member = models.ForeignKey(Staff_Member)

    #status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    def __unicode__(self):
        full_name = self.client.name +'\'s '+ self.project_text
        return full_name
    def project_name(self):
        return self.project_text
    name = client.name
```

## next file

projects.admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from clients.models import Project, Status, Client
from clients.admin import StatusInline, Staff_MemberInline

class ClientInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Client
    extra = 1

#class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
#   inlines = [Staff_MemberInline, ClientInline]

#admin.site.unregister(Project)

admin.site.register(Project)#, ProjectAdmin)
```

## next file

projects.models

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from clients.models import *
# Create your models here.
```

I'm pretty new to stackoverflow, so if there's a way I'm missing to make this more eye-friendly let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change `extra = 1` to a higher number. More info [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/admin/#extra).